# How to play sound onclick of button in layout?

Tags: android, media-player

I have a layout in which multiple button is showing.onclick of button one sound play respectively.My code is like as but its not work:-

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    resetPlayer();
    int index = 0;
    if (view.equals(objbutton1))
        index = R.raw.sound1;

    while (true) {
        this.objplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, index);
        this.objplayer.setLooping(false);
        this.objplayer.start();
        this.objplayer
                .setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        MainActivity.this.objplayer.release();
                        MainActivity.this.objplayer = null;

                    }
                }
                );
        if(view.equals(objbutton2))
        {
            index=R.raw.sound2;
            continue;

        }
        if(view.equals(objbutton3))
        {
            index=R.raw.sound3;
            continue;

        }
        if(view.equals(objbutton4))
        {
            index=R.raw.sound4;
            continue;

        }
        if(view.equals(objbutton5))
        {
            index=R.raw.sound5;
            continue;

        }
        break;
    }

}

private void resetPlayer() {
    if (this.objplayer != null) {
        if (this.objplayer.isPlaying())
            this.objplayer.stop();
        this.objplayer.release();
        this.objplayer = null;
    }
```

App is playing only one sound and when click other button no sound be changed

Comment: why are you using `while(true)`?

Comment: because I want to play sound till completion,please suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), index);
                    mp.start();
```

Like...

```
 private MediaPlayer mp; // declare it in public area.

    public void onClick(View view) {
    int index = 0;
    if (view.equals(objbutton1)){
        index = R.raw.sound1;
            if(mp !=null && mp.isPlaying()) mp.stop();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), index);
            mp.start();
        }
        if(view.equals(objbutton2))
        {
            index=R.raw.sound2;
            if(mp !=null && mp.isPlaying()) mp.stop();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), index);
            mp.start();
        }
        if(view.equals(objbutton3))
        {
            index=R.raw.sound3;
          if(mp !=null && mp.isPlaying()) mp.stop();
          mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), index);
         mp.start();
        }
        if(view.equals(objbutton4))
        {
            index=R.raw.sound4;
          if(mp !=null && mp.isPlaying()) mp.stop();
          mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), index);
         mp.start();
        }
        if(view.equals(objbutton5))
        {
            index=R.raw.sound5
          if(mp !=null && mp.isPlaying()) mp.stop();
         mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), index);
         mp.start();
        }
}
```

And in `onDestroy()`put this `mp.release();`

Comment: Hi This is not working for me my requirement is that suppose I click first button sound start ,here two cases first if I didn't press any other button then first sound will be playing till completion other case if i press other button then release first and other sound will be playing.